# Write function in R and get Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Tags: r, function, syntax, syntax-error

(MAC) My R version is: 3.6.1 GUI 1.70 El Capitan build (7684). And I tried to write a function:

```
myfunction <- founction(x) {
     y <- rnorm(100)
     mean(y)
}
```

Then I copy and paste this in Console, though I got the result: mean, I also got two errors about "{":

```
myfunction <- founction(x) {

>Error: unexpected '{' in "myfunction <- founction(x) {"    
y <- rnorm(100)
mean(y)

[1] 0.0758422

}
```

> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Could someone give me some advice? Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo. Use `function(x)` and not `founction(x) `

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss type `function()` just remove the letter `o`:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry for my carelessness.